# Replace Product page link with custom link in PRODUCT LISTING (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have only 2 products. I want to provide custom link to each respective product on product listing page.

I am using below code...

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_a_custom_button', 5 );
function add_a_custom_button() {
global $product;
if (is_product() == 3557 || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag()):

?>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <a class="button custom-button" href="https://example.com/redirect/3557/">Buy @ Store1</a>
</div>
<?php
endif;

if (is_product() == 3541 || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag()):

?>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <a class="button custom-button" href="https://example.com/redirect/3541/">Buy @ Store2</a>
</div>
<?php
endif;
```

The issue with above code is that it shows both html buttons for each product.

Answer (score 1):

I revised your code that you use in `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` action hook. You can get prodcut id by `$product->get_id()`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_a_custom_button', 5 );
function add_a_custom_button() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->get_id() == 3557 && ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) ): ?>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <a class="button custom-button" href="https://example.com/redirect/3557/">Buy @ Store1</a>
        </div>
    <?php
    endif;

    if ( $product->get_id() == 3541 && ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) ): ?>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <a class="button custom-button" href="https://example.com/redirect/3541/">Buy @ Store2</a>
        </div>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Also if you want to change the loop product default link you can use the `woocommerce_loop_product_link` filter hook.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', 'change_product_permalink_based_on_product', 99, 2 );
 
function change_product_permalink_based_on_product( $link, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_id() === 3557 ){
        $link = 'https://example.com/redirect/3557/';   
    }
    if ( $product->get_id() === 3541 ){
        $link = 'https://example.com/redirect/3541/';   
    }
    return $link;
}
```